# Mysql: SUM joined table value

Tags: php, mysql, join, sum

I have a problem with joins and `SUM()`.

I have two tables, `agents(id, name)` and `orders(id, agent_id, total)`.

Now, I need a list of all agents counting how many orders and the total of all orders they placed. Here is my basic query:

```
SELECT
    agents.*,
    COUNT(DISTINCT orders.id) total_orders,
    SUM(orders.total) total_amount
FROM agents
LEFT JOIN orders ON agents.id = orders.agent_id
GROUP BY agents.id
```

The `total_orders` is correct, but the `total_amount` is not. Every agent has the wrong `SUM()` and even those who didn't order anything have a value.

Is it possible in one query? I don't want to query again in a loop.

Comment: You dont need `DISTINCT orders.id` if `order.id` id pk on the order table.

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and expected output. I dont see how that query give you wrong sum.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a left join, replace `LEFT JOIN` by `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    agents.*,
    COUNT(DISTINCT orders.id) total_orders,
    SUM(orders.total) total_amount
FROM agents
JOIN orders ON agents.id = orders.agent_id
GROUP BY agents.id
```

The wrong result you were getting is caused by the fact that a *left join* will retrieve a row from *orders* table even if there is no record that has an agent_id equal to agents.id

A single join, on the other hand, will not retrieve agents that don't have orders.

Oh, then you need from all agents and want 0 for the total for those that don't have orders... then the left join should work. Otherwise you could do this:

```
SELECT
    agents.*,
    COUNT(DISTINCT orders.id) total_orders,
    SUM(CASE WHEN orders.id IS NULL then 0 ELSE orders.total END) total_amount
FROM agents
LEFT JOIN orders ON agents.id = orders.agent_id
GROUP BY agents.id
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the other half of the problem, but now the agents that do not have any orders do not show up anymore.

Comment: You dont need that `CASE` SUM ignore nulls

Comment: That's strange, because this is like my original query. To be honest though, I have other joins inside that query, I after a bit of trying, there was another LEFT JOIN that messed up my results.

Comment: In case you get all NULL is easy `COALESCE(SUM(column),0)`

Comment: Hey @JuanCarlosOropeza I also have Oropeza as last name, I'm Roberto Oropeza Gamarra in Bolivia! Hi cousin :)